# Why aren't my serializer method fields being called?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have the following django model:

```
class HelpItem(TimeStampMixin):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='help_items', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
description = models.TextField()
support_choice = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    choices=SubscriptionPlan.SUPPORT_CHOICES, default=SubscriptionPlan.EMAIL
)
parent_entity = models.ForeignKey(ParentEntity, related_name='help_items', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
```

Im sending a post request to create a HelpItem through this view:

```
class HelpItemView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = HelpItemSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        help_item = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={
            'user': request.user, 'selected_parent_entity': request.selected_parent_entity
        })
        help_item.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        help_item = help_item.save()
        return Response(self.serializer_class(help_item).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

And this is my serializer:

```
class HelpItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    parent_entity = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    support_choice = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = HelpItem
        fields = ['description', 'support_choice', 'parent_entity', 'user']

    def get_user(self, obj):
        return self.context['user'].id

    def get_parent_entity(self, obj):
        return get_parent_entity_for_configurations(obj.user, self.context['selected_parent_entity'])

    def get_support_choice(self, obj):
        try:
            return Subscription.objects.get(parent_entity=obj.parent_entity).subscription_plan.support
        except Subscription.DoesNotExist:
            print('No subscription exists.')
```

Shouldn't the method fields be called before the serializer tries to save the HelpItem object? I get the following error:

**null value in column "user_id" of relation "smartsign_helpitem" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (22, 2023-10-27 14:57:23.696476+00, 2023-10-27 14:57:23.696497+00, need help, null, null, 1).**

So basically the description is accessed but support choice sets to default value (1) and the user and parent entity columns are null. Why?

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting how those fields work. A SerializerMethodField is a `read_only` field and hence they're not evaluated inside the serializer create method. You either change the field type or customize the create method. Or even better delete the method fields leaving the ModelSerializer do the job and extending the `to_representation` method if you want to modify the data during reads.